# A question on Zech's Logarithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, discrete-logarithms

I was reading the chapter on *Discrete logarithms over finite fields* in **Handbook of Finite fields**, specifically [this online reference](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/%7Eodlyzko/doc/discrete.logs.hff.pdf) to the chapter on discrete logs.

In Remark 11.6.10 (reproduced below)

> [image]

what does the author mean when they say, **aside from boundary cases** in the last sentence?

Comment: My first guess is that it refers to the possibility when $g^n=-1$ and $Z(n)$ is undefined, because $1+g^n=0$ is not an element of the multiplicative group. The last sentence uses $Z(n-m)$. When that is undefined, we also have $g^m=g^n=0.$

Comment: ^should have written $g^m+g^n=0$. Damn typos.